# Why did Avon do this at the end?

Tags: blakes-7

**Spoilers obviously**

In the last episode of *Blake's 7*, entitled "Blake", Avon and the crew discover Blake as a bounty hunter.

However, in the climax, Tarrant suggests to Avon that Blake has betrayed their rebellion, but Blake explains that it was all a setup.

Avon, then shoots Blake, killing him.

**Avon:**

> Have you betrayed us? Have YOU... betrayed... ME?

**Blake:**

> I set all this up! I was waiting for you!

But then Avon sighs a big "Yessssss...." as if he believes Blake, but then pulls the trigger! But why? I'm trying to figure out whether Avon believed Blake or not, and what the "Yessss" was if not, and why shoot him if so

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characters_of_Blake%27s_7#:%7E:text=In%20the%20series%20finale%2C%20Avon,and%20responds%20by%20shooting%20Blake.) says that Avon believed he had been betrayed by Blake, but leaves out this nuance.

Comment: Sounds like a sarcastic "yes", like when someone say: "suuuure...."

Comment: @Clockwork - I don't know, given Avon's state of mind at the time, I doubt even he would be making a snarky comment (and if he did it would be a bit more witty!) - it seemed more like shocked realisation than sarcasm.

Answer (score 4):

This entry from the TV tropes page on Blakes 7 clarifies the character motivation for Avon

> One Dialogue, Two Conversations: A dark, *dark* variant, and a literal example of Poor Communication Kills. Blake assumes he's explaining the situation. Avon assumes he's confessing to a betrayal. It doesn't help that Blake's behaviour towards Tarrant has been equally open to misinterpretation. The conversation goes something like this:
> Blake: Avon; it's me, Blake...
> Avon: Stand still! Have you betrayed us? Have you betrayed me?
> Blake: Tarrant doesn't understand—
> Avon: Neither do I!
> Blake: I set all this up! (What he means is that he's set up an anti-Federation network and wants Avon to join. The paranoid Avon thinks it means that Blake has set him up.)
> Avon: Yes!
> Blake: Avon, I was waiting for you...

So, Avon says "Yes" in answer to a statement by Blake but he has fatally misunderstood Blake's meaning. From TV Tropes...

> Poor Communication Kills: Tarrant falls for Blake's bounty hunter act and tells Avon that Blake has betrayed them. Avon, who really should know Blake better than that, aims his gun at Blake, who, instead of explaining the truth coherently, just comes out with vague statements like "I set all this up!", all of which Avon misinterprets until he finally snaps and pumps Blake full of gunfire.

It's also worth noting that in the last few episodes of Blake's 7 Avon is heavily implied to be psychotic and his decisions and judgements to be highly questionable. In the earlier episode Gold he almost gets the whole crew killed and his actions actually benefit the federation. His response is to laugh maniacally. At the start of the final episode there is a pointed discussion about psychopaths and murderers, with the camera cutting back to Avon for emphasis. See this entry again from the TV Tropes page.

> I Resemble That Remark!
> Avon: It is the day of the bounty hunter. [cut to close-up of Vila] Thieves, [cut to close-up of Dayna, pan to Soolin] killers, [cut to close-up of Tarrant] mercenaries, [cut to close-up of Avon, who gives a Psychotic Smirk] ...psychopaths, are as unwelcome now as the farmers once were.

You can read the whole (very detailed entry) on this episode here...

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Recap/BlakesSevenS4E13Blake